# nix-shell stuck on Building library for hnix

Tags: plutus, nix, nix-shell, macos

I'm just gonna post a problem that I've been experiencing for a few days (and having a hard time searching for the answer on the internet) and the solution, so that future questions can refer to this solution.

**Hardware**

I'm using Macbook Pro Intel 2020, macOS Monterrey Beta 6

**Problem**

So the problem was when I was running `nix-shell` in the plutus repository for the first time, and after downloading all the dependencies, the `nix-shell` stuck at `Building library for hnix-#.#.#` and `[1 of 50] Compiling Nix.Atoms`.

What I did before compiling was installing Nix from the official documentation https://nixos.org/download.html

I also did configure the binary cache from https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus#iohk-binary-cache

Also tried to start with and without https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus#nix-on-macos

All to no success, still stuck at `Building library for hnix-#.#.#` and `[1 of 50] Compiling Nix.Atoms`

Comment: can I ask how you installed nix-darwin ?
I have the same issue as you had (Building library for hnix-#.#.# and [1 of 50] Compiling Nix.Atoms.)
I get this error when I try to install it: ~ % nix-build https://github.com/LnL7/nix-darwin/archive/master.tar.gz -A installer
./result/bin/darwin-installer error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I), at /nix/store/v1rhxl3ln24zlx8dbmhcrwbwydfmzj6a-master.tar.gz/default.nix:1:13
zsh: no such file or directory: ./result/bin/darwin-installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was simply to install `nix-darwin`

https://github.com/LnL7/nix-darwin

simply follow the instruction on the github page above, and now I can access my `nix-shell`

Comment: What is `nix-darwin` and why does installing it fix this issue?

Comment: @runeks it's like a driver or plugin to make nix compatible with macos

Comment: where did read this? As far as I can see it's a way to configure macOS using a declarative configuration (similar to NixOS). 
I don't see the connection between this and fixing `nix-build` hanging when building `hnix`.

Comment: I've installed `nix-darwin` but still have the same behavior.

Comment: @DanielCukier which terminal application and CPU architecture do you use? On my MacBook Pro M1, I just experienced the compilation of `Nix.Atoms` hang in iTerm2 running with Rosetta emulation (so that the command `arch` run in this terminal outputs `i386`). Then I tried to compile using the built-in Terminal app _without_ Rosetta emulation (so that the command `arch` run in this terminal outputs `arm64`) and this successfully compiled `Nix.Atoms`. Given that OP is on Intel hardware it may, somehow, be the terminal application that causes the hang...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac M1 Pro and my issue had to do with my `ghc` installation. I had installed version `8.10.7` through `nix-darwin` and when I switched from that installation to the same version of `ghc` installed using `ghcup` the problem disappeared (as a side note, when you're in the nix-shell, make sure you're using the shell's version of ghc and not your own, should be 8.10.4.20210212).

If that still doesn't solve your problem, I would suggest downloading the repo that broke and try running `cabal build --verbose` inside of it, that's how I figured out what the problem was.
Check what the `src` is of the nix derivation that breaks:

```
$ nix show-derivation /nix/store/kkjbrl5bbpmirwfhhs89k1q7ahm7zqih-hnix-lib-hnix-0.14.0.5.drv

{
   ...
   "src": "/nix/store/ymkyz2z612zsi183x5mjqbn65vy1a6li-hnix-0.14.0.5.tar.gz",
   ...
}
```

The problem I had was that the `cabal build` gave me a Clang error due to some missing library (libz).